# Is this a good UMP implementation?

Tags: java, android, admob, gdprconsentform

I am implementing UMP sdk in my app and it is working apparently, but I want to ensure that this is the correct way of implementing it:

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private ConsentInformation consentInformation;
  private ConsentForm consentForm;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    consent();
   }

    public void consent() {
        ConsentRequestParameters params = new ConsentRequestParameters
                .Builder()
                .setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(false)
                .build();

        consentInformation = UserMessagingPlatform.getConsentInformation(this);
        consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(this,
                params,
                new ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateSuccessListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentInfoUpdateSuccess() {
                        // The consent information state was updated.
                        // You are now ready to check if a form is available.
                        if (consentInformation.isConsentFormAvailable()) {
                            loadForm();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentInfoUpdateFailure(FormError formError) {
                        // Handle the error.
                    }
                });

    }

    public void loadForm() {
        // Loads a consent form. Must be called on the main thread.
        UserMessagingPlatform.loadConsentForm(
                this,
                new UserMessagingPlatform.OnConsentFormLoadSuccessListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormLoadSuccess(ConsentForm consentForm) {
                        MainActivity.this.consentForm = consentForm;
                        if (consentInformation.getConsentStatus() == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.REQUIRED) {
                            consentForm.show(
                                    MainActivity.this,
                                    new ConsentForm.OnConsentFormDismissedListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onConsentFormDismissed(FormError formError) {
                                            if (consentInformation.getConsentStatus() == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.OBTAINED) {
                                          MobileAds.initialize(this, initializationStatus -> {
        });
                                            }

                                            // Handle dismissal by reloading form.
                                            loadForm();
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                },
                new UserMessagingPlatform.OnConsentFormLoadFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormLoadFailure(FormError formError) {
                        loadForm();
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

I have three questions:

1- Is my implementation looking good?

2- Is it a good way to MobileAds.initialize() when ConsentStatus is ConsentStatus.OBTAINED as I have done?

3- I don't have to do anything more, right? I mean when the user accepts or declines the Form, google will automatically personalize ads without my need of managing that, right? I mean, I don't have to code the personalization part, right?